# React-native-copilot v3 - Error "Can't find variable: React"

Tags: react-native, expo

i have this error ("Can't find variable: React") on my snack expo
https://snack.expo.dev/@priami/copilot

try v3 but not work! help me

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
import React from 'react';
```

or

```
import * as React from 'react';
```

at the top of the index.js file
or read the error message where is missings

```
\node_modules\react-native-copilot\dist\index.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't installed react.

```
npm i react
```